# select keys - small data store operation

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Looking at optimizing a project utilizing cloud datastore. Would the following query be considered a small datastore operation for billing purposes?

select **key** from Kind where condition = FALSE

My understanding is the select without the condition is. I haven't found documentation confirming the above query.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [Pricing Page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing) -

> Small operations include:
>
> Calls to allocate Cloud Datastore IDs. Keys-only queries. A keys-only
>   query is counted as a single entity read for the query itself. The
>   individual results are counted as small operations. Projection queries
>   that do not use the distinct on clause. This type of query is counted
>   as a single entity read for the query itself. The individual results
>   are counted as small operations.

The example query you have posted is a Keys-only query, so I would say is considered a small operation (it is counted as one entity read).